# Ice40 SB_IO primitive input has glitches

Tags: fpga, verilog, swd

I am trying to implement SWD protocol on ICE40 USB stick using Verilog. I have designed the SWDIO as `inout` in my program whose direction is controlled by a wire variable using `SB_IO` primitive.

```
SB_IO #(
    .PIN_TYPE(6'b 1010_01),
    .PULLUP(1'b0)
    ) flash_io_buf (
    .PACKAGE_PIN(io_swd_data),
    .OUTPUT_ENABLE(swd_out_dir),
    .D_OUT_0(swd_out_data),
    .D_IN_0(swd_in_data)
    );
```

When swd_out_dir holds value 1, it outputs everything on the `inout` line very well. When swd_out_dir holds value 0, I see random glitch on the line. I am not sure what is the problem here. For reference the image is added:

[image]

The yellow part is when the swd_out_dir is 1, and beyond that it is set to 0. This image is taken when the SWDIO was only connected to the logic analyzer.

UPDATE:
When the line is connected to a target here is the output:
[image]
Line 0 is the swd_out_dir to control the SWDIO direction Line 2 is SWDIO and Line 3 is SWDCLK. As you can see when swd_out_dir is 0 the data on the line has glitches.

I have tried same target with other SWD ddebuggers and thy work perfectly OK.

Comment: Where does the "swd_out_dir" come from? Is the debug output maybe registered (clocked) while the swd_out_dir itself might be glitching? Have you tried fixed values for swd_out_dir or PIN_OUTPUT_ENABLE_REGISTERED?

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is driving the line, and both the FPGA and the logic analyzer are high-impedance inputs, then small electromagnetic fields inducing small currents will cause large voltage fluctuations that eventually get clamped by the protection diodes on the inputs (which is harmless because the currents are small).

If you connect this to an actual target, this should disappear -- so there is no problem.

Comment: Hi Simon. Thanks for your reply. I have updated the question with logic analyzer output when the SWDIO is connected to a target. As you can the see the output has glitches even when it is connected to the target.